# Error in cut.default in R

Tags: r

I have a error but I don't know how to resolve it. This is my code :

```
babbie$CHLDIDEL <- cut(babbie$CHLDIDEL, c(0, 1, 2, 3, 8))
table(babbie$CHLDIDEL)
##(0,1] (1,2] (2,3] (3,8] 
##   17   502   217   153 

babbie$CHLDIDEL <- cut(babbie$CHLDIDEL,c(0, 1, 2, 3, 8), include.lowest = TRUE,labels = c("0", "1", "2", "3", ">4"))
##Error in cut.default(babbie$CHLDIDEL, c(0, 1, 2, 3, 8), include.lowest = TRUE,  : 
##  'x' doit être numérique

table(babbie$CHLDIDEL)
##(0,1] (1,2] (2,3] (3,8] 
##   17   502   217   153
```

Comment: Try to provide a reproducible example (e.g. provide some data). It seems that you are passing a variable which is not numeric to `cut`. Maybe you already have the `character` results from your first try on `cut` stored in `babbie$CHLDIDEL`, check with `class(babbie$CHLDIDEL)`.

Comment: "'x' must be numeric" is roughly the translation of  "'x' doit être numérique" fyi. just post your data and analysis plan here, and we will take care of that for you.